# Can't I pause my server On Rackspace as Like AWS?

Tags: amazon-aws, rackspace

I am using AWS and I can create instance and keep it stopped if I don't need it. It beocmes handy as I can test/switch back/forth to several differently configured instances and don't loos any of them. I just need to pay the monthly storage price I am consuming, not the server price.

Now, on rackspace faq, I saw they doesn't support any 'suspension' status:http://www.rackspace.com/cloud/servers/faq/ (question titile: "If I am not using my server or do not have traffic to it, do I still have to pay for it?")

So, is it so, I can't keep my server in stop mode? Or did I understand something wrong?

It seems to me, if I purchase a server, I will have to continue to use it and if I want to stop for some days, I will have to delete the server completely with complete configuration and when I will be back to use it, I will have to reconfigure the whole server again? Is it so?

Answer (score 4):

No, Rackspace doesn't have the equivalent of "stopping" an instance. If you delete the server it's gone, including any local backups.

You can, however create an image of the server before you delete it. You can then restore the server later by doing a "Create Server From Image...".

Comment: Oh, that's a good news though, Thanks. So, my images will be stored as storage on my rackspace account and I will be charged for that storage, right?

Comment: Yes, thats right. they appear as files in the `cloudservers` container in your Cloud Files.